# Need to generate 9 unique integers less than 100 such that no two has sum equal to another one/two numbers

Tags: vb.net, random

I need to generate 9 unique integers less than 100, such that there exists no numbers x,y and z such that x + y = z and no numbers a,b,c and d such that a + b = c + d in VB.

Here's my VB code, but it generates number sets that doesn't satisfy the latter condition.

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Numbers(9) As Integer
    Dim w As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim z As Integer
S:
    Randomize()
    Numbers(1) = CInt(Int((99 * Rnd()) + 1))
    w = 2
    Do While w < 10
        Numbers(w) = CInt(Int((99 * Rnd()) + 1))
        x = 1
        Do While x < w
            If Numbers(w) = Numbers(x) Then
                GoTo S
            End If
            x = x + 1
        Loop
        w = w + 1
    Loop
    w = 1
    x = 1
    y = 1
    Do While w < 10
        x = 1
        y = 1
        Do While x < 10
            y = 1
            Do While y < 10
                If Numbers(y) = Numbers(x) + Numbers(z) Then
                    GoTo S
                End If
                y = y + 1
            Loop
            x = x + 1
        Loop
        w = w + 1
    Loop
    w = 1
    x = 1
    y = 1
    z = 1
    Do While w < 10
        x = 1
        y = 1
        z = 1
        Do While x < 10
            y = 1
            z = 1
            Do While y < 10
                z = 1
                Do While z < 10
                    If w <> x And w <> y And w <> z And x <> y And x <> z And y <> z And Numbers(x) + Numbers(y) = Numbers(z) + Numbers(w) Then
                        GoTo S
                    End If
                    z = z + 1
                Loop
                y = y + 1
            Loop
            x = x + 1
        Loop
        w = w + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox(Numbers(1) & " " & Numbers(2) & " " & Numbers(3) & " " & Numbers(4) & " " & Numbers(5) & " " & Numbers(6) & " " & Numbers(7) & " " & Numbers(8) & " " & Numbers(9))
End Sub
End Class
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not use SO for your college assignments.

Comment: This is not a college assignment. This is to create levels for this game: http://store.steampowered.com/app/371330

Comment: i would recommend to bulld a table of (all) numbers less than 100 and their sums (which should be less than 100 as well) by two (this can be built only once and re-used/re-loaded) in every routine. Then use this pre-computed table to speed up the process of  finding your 9 numbers

Comment: It seems like you are using VB6 to write VB.Net. using `Randomize()` and `GoTo` is very old fashion and considered bad programming in .net

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012. What should I use instead?

Comment: delete all that and start over.  When you pick a number, it is a *candidate*.  Write a function to scan the array (a list would be easier) to see if any 2 values add up to that candidate.  If True, discard the candidate, Else add it.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the case a + b = c + d ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my suggestion.
I think you'll find it more readable:

```
Private Function CreateArray() As Integer()
    Dim Target As Integer()
    '' Create a list of all integers from 1 to 100, randomly sorted.
    Dim Source As List(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).OrderBy(Function(orderby) Guid.NewGuid()).ToList()

    Target = New Integer(8) {}
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each CurrentNumber As Integer In Source

        If ValidateNumber(CurrentNumber, Target) Then
            Target(i) = CurrentNumber
            i += 1
        End If
        If i = 9 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return Target

End Function

Private Function ValidateNumber(Number As Integer, Target As Integer()) As Boolean
    if Target.Length > 1 then '' otherwise there is no need to test at all
        For i As Integer = 0 To Target.Length - 3
            For j As Integer = i + 1 To Target.Length - 2
                '' First condition: the sum of any two numbers must be different than any other number
                If Target(i) + Target(j) = Number OrElse Target(i) + Number = Target(j) OrElse Target(j) + Number = Target(i) Then
                    Return False
                End If

                For k As Integer = j + 1 To Target.Length - 1
                    '' Second condition: the sum of any two numbers must be different than the sum of any other two numbers
                    If Target(i) + Target(j) = Target(k) + Number OrElse Target(i) + Target(k) = Target(k) + Number OrElse Target(i) + Number = Target(j) + Target(k) Then
                        Return False
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    end if
    Return True
End Function
```

You can see an example in [this fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OaUzyE)

**Update**
I think I've found the problem in the second condition: in the second part of it I wrote `Target(i) + Target(k) = Target(k) + Number`, but it should have been `Target(i) + Target(k) = Target(j) + Number`.

I've found the problem while editing my `ValidateNumber` to be more readable by adding meaningful named variables for the numbers.
This is yet another reason why you should always use meaningful named variables.

```
Private Function ValidateNumber(Number As Integer, Target As Integer()) As Boolean
    Dim First, Second, Third As Integer
    If Target.Length > 1 Then '' otherwise there is no need to test at all
        For i As Integer = 0 To Target.Length - 3
            First = Target(i)
            For j As Integer = i + 1 To Target.Length - 2
                Second = Target(j)
                '' First condition: the sum of any two numbers must be different than any other number
                If First + Second = Number OrElse First + Number = Second OrElse Second + Number = First Then
                    Return False
                End If

                For k As Integer = j + 1 To Target.Length - 1
                    Third = Target(k)
                    '' Second condition: the sum of any two numbers must be different than the sum of any other two numbers
                    If First + Second = Third + Number OrElse First + Third = Second + Number OrElse First + Number = Second + Third Then
                        Return False
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

I've also updated the fiddle, so you can test it yourself.

Comment: I've updated my answer since the 2 conditions should not be nested

Comment: I am getting pairs of numbers with same sume using this code. Please look.

Comment: I'll check it again later today or tomorow. Can't do it right now

Comment: I don't actually have the time to look at it now, only tomorow. What condition is failing, the first or the second?

Comment: I think I've found the problem, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use random number for this, unless you feel lucky. Just iterate all the possible combinations and wait.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim n(9) As Integer ' Contains the list of 9 numbers
    Dim sums As New List(Of Integer) ' List of the sums of all the numbers

    n(0) = 1

    For x As Integer = 1 To 8
        n(x) = n(x - 1) + 1
    Next

    Do
        Dim x As Integer = 8

        ' Get the next number from the list
        Do
            n(x) += 1

            If n(x) >= 100 Then
                If x = 0 Then
                    Exit Do
                End If

                n(x) = n(x - 1) + 1
                x -= 1
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        ' Get the list of all the sums
        sums.Clear()

        For a As Integer = 0 To 7
            For b As Integer = a + 1 To 8
                sums.Add(n(a) + n(b))
            Next
        Next

        Dim wrong As Boolean = False

        ' Is a sum equal to a number in the list?
        For Each s As Integer In sums
            For x = 0 To 8
                If s = n(x) Then
                    wrong = True
                End If
            Next
        Next

        ' Are two sums equal to each other?
        For a As Integer = 0 To sums.Count - 2
            For b As Integer = a + 1 To sums.Count - 1
                If sums(a) = sums(b) Then
                    wrong = True
                End If
            Next
        Next

        ' Everything passed!
        If Not wrong Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    For Each x As Integer In n
        Console.WriteLine(x)
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("Done")
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I try it by a method to generate your random numbers.

Method in **Vb.NET**:

```
Public Function GenerateRandomNumbers(min As Integer, max As Integer, count As Integer, exceptNumbers As Integer()) As List(Of Integer)
    If count > max - min Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("your count is more than min and max range!")
    End If

    Dim lst = New List(Of Integer)()
    Dim rand = New Random()

    While count >= 0
        Dim value = rand.[Next](min, max)

        Dim upValue As Boolean = False
        While lst.Any(Function(x) x = value) OrElse exceptNumbers.Any(Function(x) x = value)
            If value < min Then
                value += 1
                upValue = True
            ElseIf value > max Then
                Exit While
            ElseIf upValue Then
                value += 1
            Else
                value -= 1
            End If
        End While

        lst.Add(value)
        count -= 1
    End While

    Return lst
End Function
```

Now, you can use that this model:

```
Dim lst = GenerateRandomNumbers(0, 100, 9, New Integer() {1, 5, 8, 6, 10, 2})
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this take care of the conditions I mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, Now that codes work correct! I was forget the except list, Excuse me about that